Código para detectar números primos
He encontrado el siguiente código para ver si un número es primo o no:
from itertools import takewhile
from math import sqrt
i = 2
while i < 100:
    c = range(2,int(sqrt(i))+1)
    x = takewhile(lambda j: i%j != 0,c) # tomamos elementos de c mientras que no dividan a i
    y = list(x)
    z = len(y)
    if z == len(c):
        print(i,' es primo')
    else:
        div = c[z]
        print('{0} es igual a {1} * {2}.'.format(i,div,i//div))
    i += 1
print('Fin')


Hay una parte que no entiendo. La condición para que un número sea primo es que solo sea divisible por 1 y por sí mismo. Según esto, si tenemos un número n tendríamos que dividirlo por todos los números desde el 2 hasta n-1. Esa "lista" de números la obtenemos a partir de c, la cual no llegaría a n-1. Por ejemplo, cuando i=5 c sería igual a range(2,3) así que la función takewhile() dividiría el número 5 sólo por 2, olvidando los números hasta n-1 (en este caso, los números 3 y 4). ¿Es un fallo en este código o hay algo que se me pasa?
Gracias de antemano

Efectivamente un número es primo si solo es divisible entre el mismo y la unidad. Pero  vamos a darle la vuelta, para cualquier número compuesto se da que:
N = P1ᵃ * P2ᵇ...

dónde cada Pn es un factor primo del mismo y ᵃ,ᵇ,... son los exponentes o la multiplicidad (las veces que ese factor primo se repite).
Bien, un número compuesto, por definición, debe tener al menos dos factores primos distintos o uno solo pero con multiplicidad mayor a uno.
Para saber si un número es compuesto basta con encontrar un divisor/factor suyo distinto de uno o el mismo, no hay que encontrarlos todos, con uno que encontremos sabemos que ese número es compuesto, o lo que es lo mismo, no es primo. Ahora llega la pregunta:
¿Cuál es el valor máximo que puede tener el factor más pequeño de un número compuesto dado?
En el caso de los cuadrados (4, 9, 25, ...) el menor (y mayor) factor es su raíz cuadrada, obvio:
25 = 5 * 5
49 = 7 * 7

En el caso de los compuestos que no son cuadrados, no es difícil darse cuenta de que siempre al menos un factor debe estar comprendido entre uno y la raíz cuadrada de N. Si dos factores cualquiera de N fueran mayores a la raíz cuadrada de N, multiplicados darían un número mayor a N...
Por lo tanto sabemos que:

De ser compuesto, un número siempre tendrá un factor primo (un divisor por tanto) igual o menor a su raíz cuadrada.

Para saber si un número es compuesto basta con encontrar un solo divisor no trivial (que no sea 1 o el mismo).



Comprobar solo hasta sqrt(N) como hace tu código es la segunda optimización más simple
de cualquier test de primalidad por tentativa.

Tu mismo mencionas que para el 5 solo se comprueba el 2 y no 3 o 4:

En el caso del 4 no tiene sentido comprobarlo, no existen primos pares distintos del 2. Cualquier número par tiene como factor el 2, si N no es par (no es divisible por 2) probar con cualquier número par superior es perder el tiempo...

Esta es la primera optimización obvia de los test de primalidad por
división por tentativa, no testar jamás la primalidad de un número par ni la divisibilidad de un posible primo entre
un numero par, el único primo par es el 2.

Optimización que tu algoritmo no implementa por cierto, y reduce a la mitad las comprobaciones y las divisiones...

El caso del 3, supongamos que 3 es un factor primo de 5, como debemos tener al menos dos factores primos para crear un número compuesto, o un factor con multiplicidad mayor a uno, tenemos dos posibilidades (hay más, pero si el número tuviera más de dos factores se aplica lo mismo que en la segunda opción):

3 * 3 = 9 (que es mayor que 5)
3 * P = 5

La primera opción obviamente no es posible. En el caso de la segunda, P tiene que ser menor que 3, si o si. Si 3 * 3 ya es mayor de 5, para cualquier P > 3,  3 * P también lo será. Si P es menor que 3, antes de llegar a comprobar la divisibilidad entre 3 habríamos probado con ese P y ya sabríamos si el número es compuesto.


Si 5 fuera compuesto habríamos encontrado al menos un factor suyo menor a sqrt(5) (que es menor que 3). Comprobar la divisibilidad más allá es perder el tiempo, si no hay un factor menor o igual a la raíz cuadrada no habrá ninguno más distinto de él mismo... ya sabemos que es primo.

Si la idea es buscar los primos desde 2 hasta N, tu algoritmo tiene unos cuantos detalles que lo hacen muy ineficiente:

Compruebas la primalidad de números pares distintos del 2.

Compruebas si el número es divisible por los números pares.

Por cada número a probar almacenas una lista de bools en memoria, lista que solo usas para obtener su longitud.

Desaprovechas que ya conoces los posibles factores primos previos en cada iteración. En vez de probar la divisibilidad entre todos los impares menores a la raíz cuadrada, compruébala solo para los primos previamente obtenidos menores a ella.

Hay otras cosas subóptimas relacionadas con la implementación, como el uso de un ciclo while frente a un for-range o usar takewile + lambda (tal vez por querer usar una aproximación funcional) en vez de un simple ciclo for y un condicional o all()/any() y un condicional.


Una implementación muy simple para solventar este problema teniendo en cuenta lo explicado sería:
from math import sqrt

N = 1000

primos = [2]
for n in range(3, N, 2):      # Testear solo los impares
    root = sqrt(n)
    for factor in primos:
        if factor > root:     # Es primo
            primos.append(n)
            break
        elif n % factor == 0: # Es compuesto
            break
print(primos)

Se puede optimizar más deduciendo exactamente la lista de primos sobre los que iterar en vez de usar el primer condicional.
Almacenar los primos en un array/lista y realizar las tentativas de división solo con ellos ahorra un montón de iteraciones, son pocos en relación a N (por ejemplo, hay 168 primos menores de 1000). Para el caso del 997 nos ahorramos 5 iteraciones con respecto a probar con los impares y el ahorro es mayor según aumenta N dada la distribución de los primos. Para primos grandes simplemente la división por tentativa se vuelve impracticable.

Es cierto que un número es primo si solamente es divisible por el mismo y la unidad, pero te imaginarás que hacer un ciclo desde 1 hasta N-1 para comprobar si el número es primo es altamente ineficiente, por eso se han creado optimizaciones en los algoritmos de búsqueda de números primos que permitan que está búsqueda se haga con mayor rapidez.
A continuación te comento optimizaciones simples que podrían mejorar tu algoritmo.
Optimización 1: Todos los números primos excepto el 2 son impares, teniendo en cuenta este análisis podemos hacer un ciclo desde 3 hasta N-1 y que se incremente de dos en dos de modo que las divisiones se hagan solamente para los impares.
Optimización 2: Ningún número es divisible por un número que sea mayor a la mitad del mismo, ejemplo la mitad de 100 es 50, y 100 ya no va a ser divisible por ningún número mayor a 50, teniendo esto en cuenta podemos hacer ahora un algoritmo que solamente compruebe por los números menores a la mitad del propio número y que solamente analice los impares.
Optimización 3: Todos los divisores de un número N se pueden hallar dividiendo desde 1 hasta la raíz de N, esto optimiza mucho tu algoritmo ya que ahora harías un ciclo que compruebe solamente desde 3 hasta raíz de N, y que vaya solo por los impares.
Optimización 4: Un número es primo si no es divisible por ningún primo menor a la raíz del propio número, esto optimiza aún más tu algoritmo ya que ahora harías un ciclo que vaya comprobando solamente por los números primos menores a la raíz de N, esto tendrías que hacerlo con una lista que vaya almacenando cada número primo hallado, y a la hora de comprobar si un nuevo número es primo solamente se recorrería la lista de primos hasta que se halle un primo mayor a la raíz de N.
Existen otros algoritmos clásicos para buscar números primos como es el caso de la criba de Eratóstenes. Espero haberte dado una idea más detallada sobre la búsqueda de números primos y que te sirvan para futuras implementaciones.
